# User does not exist

Tags: login

I got this message when trying to log into comment on a post. Then I got it when I went to log into my own wordpress site.

I could find the site so it's still there.

I was using Safari to do this, as I have for quite some time, when I got the message that the used doesn't exist. Then, I tried to log in with Chrome and no problem. What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem with the cache in Safari, as you can log into your site via Chrome successfully. You have to clear it to solve the issue.

Follow these steps:

1. Click on **Safari** in the menu bar.
2. Click on **Preferences**.
3. Go to **Privacy > Manage Website Data**.
4. Click **Remove All**.
5. A dialogue box will appear. Click on **Remove Now** button to
   complete the process of clearing the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did that but there wasn't any change in the result. Not sure what to do, other than go to a different browser for that and other wordpress website if I want to comment there. I have noticed that some web browsers won't work on some sites, for example, I can't log in to YouTube, except on Chrome. This has been true for several years. Sigh!